# Property not exist in edit User API in Symfony 4

Tags: api, symfony, validation, doctrine-orm

I created the User entity and this is one of the properties of this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
 *
 * @Assert\Length(max="50")
 * @Assert\NotNull()
 */
private $firstName;
```

In Api Controller when i want to validate the user or submit form for edit user i will get the error.

the controller:

```
public function edit(Request $request, ValidatorInterface $validator)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $validator->validate($this->getUser()); # i get error here
}
```

the error is:

> Property \"firstName\" does not exist in class
>   \"Proxies\__CG__\App\Entity\User\""

but I have the `firstName` and I can use getter and setter for that.

Comment: did you clear cache?

Comment: @Ludo yes and also use rm -fr var/cache/*

Comment: It's ok when use $user = new User(); but in this case i have error.

Comment: hmm, whatabout doctrine cache? 

`php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-result`
`php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-query`
`php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata`

and any chance your cache folder is not in var/cache?

Comment: @Ludo I will test it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may try this way.

```
$user = $this->getUser();
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(YourEntity::class);
$userEntity = $repository->find($user->getId());

$validator->validate($userEntity);
```

Comment: are you using multiple user provider?

Comment: No only one named User

Comment: Ok i will edit my question and comment in here again